# Intel Edison bluetooth is not able to connect to HC-05 bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, intel-edison

I have done pairing of Intel Edison with HC-05 but whenever I try to connect Edison with HC-05 I got this.

```
   [bluetooth]# connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

    Attempting to connect to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

   [CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Connected: Yes

   Failed to connect: org.bluez.ErrorNotAvailable

   [CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Connected: No

   [bluetooth]#
```

How to establish a stable connection?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that new Edison firmware has some bluetooth problems. I could not establish a connection using bluetooth. I even used Andorid apps such as "Bluetooth spp pro" but no luck with that one either.

Eventually, I used an older version of firmware and this time, surprisingly, it worked but it took me two days to figure it out!

So, for now, the thing you can do is installing (flashing) an older version of the firmware and using that. However, I think it is not possible to do that using that wizard thing and you should do it manually.

Comment: Finally Connected!!. Instead of connecting manually I used rfcomm-server-sdp.py https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x290.html. Changed the UUID and service name matching to HC-05, got connected and receiving data.